# C#: cropping a selected area from a GdViewer that doesn't provide any cropping feature

Tags: c#, crop

I'm trying to make a crop button that takes a selected area from a gdviewer (the project is about a document scanner) there's a method called `GetRectCoordinatesOnDocument(ref int Left, ref int Top, ref int Width, ref int Height)`, to take the area selection from the `MouseModeAreaSelection`, and other method to crop:
`GdPictureStatus Crop(int ImageID, int Left, int Top, int Width, int Height)`, but I don't know how to make it work.

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - What is a 'GdViewer'?

Comment: Please post your code. I note that GdViewer's documentation already provides working example code: https://guides.gdpicture.com/content/GdPicture.NET.12~GdPicture12.GdPictureImaging~Crop.html (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Sorry, i'm targetting about Winforms, and a GdViewer is a library that i add to Visual Studio is for document viewing.